# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, javascript-objects

**I am getting the error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')**

```
const formatForecastWeather = (data) => {
    let { timezone, daily, hourly } = data;
    daily = daily.slice(1, 6).map(d => { //i am geeting error on this line 
        return {
            title: formatToLocalTime(d.dt, timezone, 'ccc'),
            temp: d.temp.day,
            icon: d.weather[0].icon
        }
    });


    hourly = hourly.slixe(1, 6).map(d => {
        return {
            title: formatToLocalTime(d.dt, timezone, 'hh:mm a'),
            temp: d.temp.day,
            icon: d.weather[0].icon
        }
    });

    return { timezone, daily, hourly };

};
```

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to help. Wherever `data` is coming from is the problem. You're expecting it to have a `data.daily` array field, and it just doesn't. Please post a [mcve] showing the whole issue.

Comment: `slixe` <--- typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an Optional [Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) ? In order to avoid “read properties of undefined error”.

```
const formatForecastWeather = (data) => {
    let { timezone, daily, hourly } = data;
    daily = daily?.slice(1, 6).map(d => { //i am geeting error on this line 
        return {
            title: formatToLocalTime(d.dt, timezone, 'ccc'),
            temp: d.temp.day,
            icon: d.weather[0].icon
        }
    });
```